# SQL Server Enable Active Directory User

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, active-directory

I work at a college a change to policy is Students windows accounts are now disabled upon creation and are only enabled upon them passing a test. Don't ask

So I can easily modify my DSADD with -disabled yes

However I need to enable them when they pass the test. I obtain the test results from a sql server so is it possible to enable the accounts that have passed the test within t-sql?

I am just thinking it is easier to schedule a job on the sql server to do this as oppose to writing a program that checks the results every 5 minutes and having to keep making sure it is running and not forget about the programs existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security comes down to SQL Sever from AD, not the other way around.

That said, you could write a query that would email you it's results.

You could write an SSIS package that would do the same thing.

Or, if you can figure out how parameterize the bits and pieces, you could write an SSIS pacakge that would use the "Execute Process Task" to send the right string to the command line.